# Localhost saying "React App" but I'm not using React. Main.js file loading HTML

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, localhost, web-development-server

I'm so confused. I'm trying to learn how to build a web app, and I started to learn `React` in another directory but stopped so I could first learn the basics. I made a new folder on my Desktop and was trying to test my routes.

On VSCode, when I click `go live` and run `npm run dev`, everything seems to be working okay. The browser address looks like this: `http://127.0.0.1:5500/public/index.html`

However, when I type in `http://localhost:3000`, there is a little icon for React and it says `React App.` I'm not using React! And, when I inspect the page and my two files: `index.html` and `main.js`, the weirdest thing happens. My `main.js` file displays all `HTML` from `index.html`! This does not happen using `http://127.0.0.1:5500/public/index.html`, though.

I cleared my cache, and I killed all processes with `ps aux | grep node` that may be using `React`. They are completely different project folders so my `node_modules` doesn't have any `React`.

I understand that running it straight from `vscode` runs all of the static files but I'm not understanding why it's registering as `React` from `localhost` for one, or why it is loading in `main.js` but the contents are all HTML from `index.html`.

More info:
in `package.json`, I have `"main": "index.js"` and under `scripts` I have `"dev": "nodemon index.js"`.
In `index.js`, I have:

```
app.get('*', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'public', 'index.html'))
});
```

In `public/index.html`, I link the script: `<script src="main.js"></script>`.

Thanks so much!